# Show everything in chrome.storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I tried to use `console.log(chrome.storage)` but it doesn't return anything helpful. I have already set some values in my extensions using `chrome.storage.sync.set` and want to see them.

I can type `console.log(localStorage)` and see everything in it. How to do such with chrome.storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait for the completion of `chrome.storage.sync.set()` action. One of the ways to do it is the callback function. The value you pass with `chrome.storage.sync.set()` is available within callback:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({'key1': 123}, function() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get("key1", function(data) {
    console.log("data", data);
  });
});
```

Comment: How to get list of all values storing in chrome.storage?

Comment: Try this: chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(all) {console.log(all)});