# Get background-script-variables in content-script - chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension, and I want to be able to load a variable from my background-script, in my  content-script.

I tried:

```
//background script

window.test = "test123";
```

‎

```
//content script

const bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage(); //here
at content-instagram.js:1
console.log(bg.test);
```

At "here", this error comes: `Uncaught TypeError: chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage is not a function at content.js:1`

Comment: Content scripts can't use most of `chrome` API so you'll have to switch to [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) or `chrome.storage`.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks. I used chrome-storage. For anyone curious, I researched a bit, and found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601091/show-everything-in-chrome-storage. and used gthacoder 's response, with the "null". Worked great.